# Why can I call File::open(...).read_to_end()?

Tags: rust

The following code works and I don't know why:

```
File::open(&some_path).read_to_end().unwrap();
```

Looking at the API docs I can see `File::open()` returning a [`IoResult`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.IoResult.html) which does not have a `read_to_end()`.

Is there some kind of syntax sugar going on? Does `Result<T, Error>` somehow turn into `Result<U, Error>`?

Documentation: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fs/struct.File.html#method.read_to_end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`read_to_end` is from the `Reader` trait and if you look there you can see that [there](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Reader.html) is an implementation for reader for `IoResult<R>` for any `R` that implements `Reader`:

```
impl<R: Reader> Reader for IoResult<R>
```

Comment: Looks like the documentation does not tell me that `IoResult` implements the trait... ok! Accepting in 5 mins.